# Pass modified video stream into Vuforia Engine?

Tags: performance, camera, augmented-reality, tracking, vuforia

Is it possible to modify the Vuforia video stream for better tracking performance?

Step 1: Get the raw pixel data from the VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.GetCameraImage();
Step 2: Modify the pixels with post processing via custom shaders in Unity. For example apply a threshold or edge detection.
Step 3: Vuforia Engine uses the modified video input to track images.

That´s the idea but I´m not sure if Vuforia is gonna pass the modified video into the Vuforia Engine then or still uses the unmodified video input for tracking?
If anybody has experience with that I would be thankful for your help! :)

Comment: Probably u want to use Vuforia FileDriver route?
https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/building-and-using-file-driver-sample

or create an external camera driver urself?
https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/creating-custom-driver

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia Engine assumes that the input images look like "natural" images. Passing an image belonging to a different domain (e.g., the result of an edge detector) is unlikely to improve tracking performance.

That said, tracking performance is affected by image quality. For example, if images are blurry, tracking robustness is going to suffer. If this is the case you might want to look at trying to adjust system camera parameters via the platform API (iOS, Android, etc.). However, please note that this might or might not be possible depending on the platform. Also, on some platforms when a device tracker like ARKit or ARCore is used, the platform tracker itself adjusts the camera parameters for good tracking performance. For example it might keep the exposure time low to reduce blur.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My idea was to use processed image targets so Vuforia generates more feature points to track (e.g. an image with a threshold or edge detection so there is more contrast on that image). But to detect and track those processed images the camera needs to have the same computer vision as on the image targets applied. I'm not sure if this would work out and improves the tracking or if it just kills the performance...

Comment: I am not sure you need to pass a modified input stream. It should be enough to use as physical target a print of the processed image used to generate the ImageTarget.

Comment: That makes sense but in my case I´ll try to track the outdoor environment based on 2D images instead of 3D model targets.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are generating the Imagetarget from the camera image itself. Please note that even if traking  "works" the poses you will get might not be geometrically correct as image target assumes a flat region with the picture taken from a view perpendicular to the flat plane.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm aware of so I'm thinking about ways to improve the tracking. So one thought was to improve it by creating more feature points through image processing and a processed video input at runtime. But I guess even then the projections gonna be to shaky. Unfortunately I'm kind of stuck to 2D Images cause a 3D scan (e.g. photogrammetrie) won't be possible.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but Vuforia has an app which can scan an environment using a iPhone/iPad with Lidar https://library.vuforia.com/tools/creator-app. The app creates an AreaTarget which can be used for tracking and reconstructs a mesh of the environment.